# will the change set deployment affect the ongoing data loading

Tags: data-loader, change-set

I came across a situation where one of my peer is uploading some records using the data loader and it may take a long time may be more than 10 hours.

My query is, what will be impact of deploying a change set which updates the workflow rules and some of the triggers that are based on the same object, where data loader is already inserting some records.

Answer (score 3):

**The impact is poor data quality on a large scale.** Data is a major strategic asset for a company and poor data is a costly expense.

A 10 hour data import suggests  a massive data set which will be hard to work with and QA. When looking at data that big, you can think of it in 3 parts

1. the data that was inserted before your CS deployment
2. The data inserted during your CS (this will take 10-
3. The data that is inserted after your CS deployment

if your goal is good data do your CS first. otherwise breakup your data loader, into pre and post  CS deployment and update the records that where pre-deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it, unless you genuinely don't care whether or not your rules are applied to the inserted records.

In a normal data loader scenario, each batch (size is often on order of 200 records) is committed as they are loaded. So as soon as each batch is loaded, those records are visible, won't be rolled back if your data load is halted, and will be eligible for all active workflow rules.

So if you successfully deploy a changeset halfway through a big data load that affects those records, insert-fired rules will fire only for the last half of the inserted records. It's possible you could also run into an org-wide lock issue that affects either your ability to deploy the changeset or insert records during the code push, but I never do this so can't say for sure under what conditions this would occur.

This illustrates part of the reason why I always recommend deploying anything of size during off-peak times (Friday evening or Saturday mornings are my times of choice for typical 9-5 businesses). You avoid data consistency issues, and you also get time to fix data and/or code up if you pick up an issue that missed QA or run into other deployment issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend deploying any changes during a data import, but I would expect that records inserted and updated after the deployment would be subjected to the new triggers and workflow rules.